# Tinymce New line event

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm developing some edits for TinyMce and I need to fire an event everytime the cursor enters an empty line (new or old line).

Only event I was able to find is `nodeChange` is there any better one?

Comment: is that even possible? I mean tinyMce is not docx. even though you see "lines", tinyMce see tags and html does not adhere to whitespace unless you add `<pre>` tag. Translating empty line to  empty `<p>` tag or `<p>` tag with `<br/>` or empty line in `<pre>` et al is very tedious task. if it has not been done, then doing so will be very hard, considering the corner cases.
So, what exactly do you need your custom event for? it is possible that there is a simpler (read easier) solution to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to work:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea',
    setup : function(editor) {
      editor.on('keyup', function(e) {

        var rng = editor.selection.getRng(true);
        var txt = rng.startContainer.textContent;

        if ( (txt.substring(rng.startOffset - 1, rng.startOffset) == '') &&
             (txt.substring(rng.startOffset, rng.startOffset + 1) == '') ) {

          console.log('empty line !');
        }


      });
    }
});
```

[This is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6LfLkqo/)

**UPDATE: This update also recognizes the lines containing only an image**

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea',
    setup : function(editor) {
      editor.on('keyup', function(e) {

        var rng = editor.selection.getRng(true);
        var txt = rng.startContainer.textContent;

        if ( (txt.substring(rng.startOffset - 1, rng.startOffset) == '') &&
             (txt.substring(rng.startOffset, rng.startOffset + 1) == '') &&
             (rng.startContainer.outerHTML.indexOf('<img')==-1)) {
          console.log('empty line !');
        }

      });
    }
});
```

[This is the new JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6LfLkqo/1/)

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much, that soulved my problem. I'm going to add mouseUp function. Just a question, isn't editor.on('keyup') deprecated, for the latest tinyMce?

Comment: For the API 3.x the documentation is this: http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp 
but I could not find anything about the API 4. 
Anyway on jsfiddle I set the version 4 and it works.

Comment: I kinda have a problem. This checks only if there is no text. But let's suppose there in link tag with image in it. This scripts recognises only text so it will say the line is empty even there is link tag with image.

Comment: Finally, after many attempts I found a solution, not elegant, but it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/k6LfLkqo/1/

Comment: @JakubKohout sorry, I don't know if you read my last replay... :)

Comment: I read your reply, but I sticked with the original one combining with with different method :) Thank you for your effort and time.